# $http(config) vs $http.get(...): What is the difference?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

According to the [Angular documentation for `$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), it seems that the constructor

`$http(config)`

and the functions

`$http.get(...)`

both return the same things - `HttpPromise`s.

So what is the difference between them? Or are they just two ways to write the exact same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$http.get(...)`, as said in the doc you gave link to, is a *shortcut method to perform GET request*. You won't be able to make any other type of request with `$http.get` - `GET` only. Note that `POST`, `PUT`, `HEAD` and `DELETE` have their corresponding shortcut methods too.

All these methods, however, are essentially the `$http(config)` calls - with `method` parameter pre-specified. Here's how it's done ([1.3.6 source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.6/src/ng/http.js#L976)):

```
createShortMethods('get', 'delete', 'head', 'jsonp');
// ...

function createShortMethods(names) {
  forEach(arguments, function(name) {
    $http[name] = function(url, config) {
      return $http(extend(config || {}, {
        method: name,
        url: url
      }));
    };
  });
}
```

Still, sometimes it's more convenient to use `$http(config)` syntax - for example, if one has to choose the request method based on some external conditions that should be easy to switch. Note that if you don't specify `method` property in `config`, `GET` is used:

```
function $http(requestConfig) {
  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    transformRequest: defaults.transformRequest,
    transformResponse: defaults.transformResponse
  };
  // ... some checks skipped
  extend(config, requestConfig);
}
```

Comment: great edit, was just about to point out other use case for `$http(config)`